# Join query issue in jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using jquery datatable with server-side processing. Just I am trying to make `join` query to produce output.

So I changed columns array to something like this:

```
$aColumns = array (
                   "u.user_id", 
                   "CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)", 
                   "u.gender", 
                   "CONCAT(a.suburb, ', ', a.zip_code)", 
                   "u.date_registered"
                 );
```

And changed query like this.

```
$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.user_id 
                    , CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
                    , u.gender
                    , CONCAT(a.suburb, ', ', a.zip_code)
                    , u.date_registered
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN user_addresses a ON a.user_id = u.user_id ".$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
```

Then I can populate the datatable. But its search, filter and sort is not working.

This kind of error I can get when I trying to search, filter or sort.

> Unknown column 'u.user_id' in 'where clause'

**Updates**
This is the output when I echo `$sQuery`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  u.user_id 
                          , CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
                          , u.gender
                          , CONCAT(a.suburb, ', ', a.zip_code)
                          , u.date_registered
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN user_addresses a ON a.user_id = u.user_id AND a.address_type = 1  
WHERE (`u.user_id` LIKE '%s%' OR `CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)` LIKE '%s%' OR `u.gender` LIKE '%s%' OR `CONCAT
(a.suburb, ', ', a.zip_code)` LIKE '%s%' OR `u.date_registered` LIKE '%s%') LIMIT 0, 10 
Unknown column 'u.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

Can anybody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you echo out the `$sQuery` variable? Then we will be able to see the values of your `where`, `order` and `limit` variables.

Comment: @Lock, Can you tell me how to echo my query in proccessing script? I simply tried like this `echo $eQuery; ` But I can not get output.

Comment: Put `echo $sQuery; exit;` just after the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping the column name in backticks, not just the column name.

For example, you have:

```
`u.user_id`
```

Where it should be:

```
u.`user_id`
```

You will need to change this for all your values in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you. In my processing script I am not sure how to it. Because `where` clause is dynamically generating like this - `if (!empty($aFilteringRules)) {
    $sWhere = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $aFilteringRules);
} else {
    $sWhere = "";
}`

Comment: You will have to look at whatever is setting the `$aFilteringRules` variable and correct it

Comment: Can you kindly look at that filtering selection in the processing script. - http://pastebin.com/mPsXqhaA

Comment: This is really a design issue. The script you have given is assuming that the values in `$aColumns` will only include field names, not table and field name (e.g. it is expecting `user_id`, not `b.user_id`. You need to redesign this code, perhaps so that the `$aColumns` is populating with the backticks and that the backticks are not added by your code, such as is seen on like 13.